# How to access getResources in Android module?

Tags: android, kotlin, module, resources

**How to access getResources in Android/kotlin module?**

I have resource in resource folder for a module (non host) in Android. i need to call getResources from a non activity class. How can I do so? getApplicationContext is not available.

Comment: Modules should be independent from applicationContext, you should pass your resource via dependency injection to your module method

Comment: Yes i agree with @Nicola use some interface and inject that interface reference in your independent module class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    public class Activity1 extends Activity {
         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             Myclass myClass = new Myclass(this);
         }
     }
```

Then you can use it in the constructor (or set it to an instance variable):

```
public class Myclass(){
    private Context context;

    public Myclass(Context current){
        this.context = current;
    }

    public getResource(){
        context.getResources().getXml(R.xml.resourcexml);
    }
}
```

You can use interface also.

Comment: Hello Elletlar. Currently not using any where in the project. Definitely analyze before use. Thank you for your suggestion.